# Spring @Scheduled timer accuracy

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-scheduled

I'm using spring-boot `@Scheduled` annotation with fixedDelay in milliseconds as documented in javadoc:

> Execute the annotated method with a fixed period in milliseconds between the end of the last invocation and the start of the next.

Code:

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelay=1000)
public void task() {
    LOG.info("START: " + System.currentTimeInMillis());
    ....do some work here...
    LOG.info("END: " + System.currentTimeInMillis());
}
```

And sometimes I get such output that time between previous task end and next task starts is less than `1000ms` for about `2-30 milliseconds`.

Is it normal due to some granularity or why is it happening? Is there any guaranties about this delta value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different ways in which you can use **@Scheduled** annotation.

According to the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html#scheduling-annotation-support-scheduled):

The **fixedRate** invokes the method every t ms but the time delay is measured from the start of the invocation. If t ms are passed and the method is still in execution then the next invocation will wait for it to finish and will invoke right after the first one. Try putting `Thread.sleep(3000)` in your method. I think that your method is taking about 950ms to complete.

If you want to wait after finishing the execution you can use **fixedDelay**.

Comment: Yeah, actually just checked, I used fixedDelay. Will fix the description

Comment: Are you getting the problem with the fixedDelay too?

Comment: Yes, I used fixedDelay from the start, just mistyped when was writing this post

Comment: please join this room:
https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/145781/discussion-between-chucksull-and-ruslan?tab=general

Comment: hi, yes, found a mistake in my code, thanks, works fine

Answer (score 0):

Obviously it cannot be guaranteed since you're most likely not on a real time system. Depending on what the CPU(s) do at the moment it can vary like that. It's quite hard to do something like that actually on most PC's due to the OS scheduling calls and so on (unless you have direct access to the CPU/GPU but even then)

Answer (score 0):

How `@Scheduled(fixedDelay=1000)` works is, it will run this void method every `1000 ms`(If this task finish execution `<` `1000 ms` or this will run asynchronously). If `>` `1000ms` it the execution task will get into a task queue in the Executor service used. There is **no** connection with the **end of task and the start of next task**  but a connection with the **start of a task and start of a next task**.

Comment: There is fixedDelay and fixedRate as already mentioned by chuckskull. And fixedDelay actually starts next execution after 1000ms (in this case) of the end of previous task